# Parent/Child methods in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to call a method within a child VUE instance and I can't figure out why it doesn't seem to be working.

My Vue is as follows:

**Parent**

```
var content = new Vue({
    el: '.content-container',
});
```

**Child**

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#form',
    parent: content,
    data: {
        postcode: null,
    },
    methods: {
        lookupAddress: function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            // Lookup Address
        },
    },
});
```

However, I keep getting the following error within Vue Dev Tools: `v-on:click="lookupAddress" expects a function value, got undefined`

Any ideas on why it's not picking up the method on the child instance? I am calling the method within the childs element.

**Edit**
My HTML markup is as follows:

```
<body>
    <div class="content-container">
        <form id="form">
            ...
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: your markup is needed

Comment: Added HTML above @YerkoPalma

Comment: Just a guess, but probably because it thinks the method lookupAddress should be on the parent vue (and it's not looking at the child). I'm not sure you should be creating nested vue instances, perhaps look into components for the child instead?

Comment: Might need to go down that route... slight pain but oh well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I'm seeing here your problem is that you're creating two Vue instances. It becomes difficult to share data and methods between instances. It's much simpler to create a single instance and use components to do the leg work. Some reading: http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html

Comment: Would you then use the component on the child instance, or remove the child instance? Bear in mind that this isn't going to be a SPA

Comment: You would use the component on the Vue instance. You let Vue know about the component via the "components" property object in a Vue instance. Like such: 

`var vm = new Vue({
    el: '.content-container',
   compontents: {
     componenteName: 'component-name'
}
});`

The documentation is quite extensive and a big part of using Vue. I'd recommend going through it in detail